# UIActivityIndicatorView not showing up in iOS UIViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uiactivityindicatorview

I want to display a gray `UIViewIndicatorView` in a view controller at the center of the view but this piece of code isn't showing anything:

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController {
    var activityIndicatorView = UIActivityIndicatorView()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .black
        displayActivityIndicator()
    }

    func displayActivityIndicator() {
        view.addSubview(activityIndicatorView)
        activityIndicatorView.style = .gray
        activityIndicatorView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        activityIndicatorView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        activityIndicatorView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40).isActive = true
        activityIndicatorView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40).isActive = true
        activityIndicatorView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        activityIndicatorView.startAnimating()
    }   
}
```

This only shows up the activity indicator view when I set the view controller's view to a color like white (excluding black).

How can I make it show up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change background to

```
view.backgroundColor = .green // for example
```

or

```
activityIndicatorView.style = .white
```

then you' ll see  it , as it's nearly a color match between the indicator and the background view

Comment: I want the view's background color to be black.

Comment: gray is very near from black

Comment: I mean the spinning wheels should be white or whatever that is.

Comment: The view background color should be strictly black.